# Find if Row has two given values with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for an easy way to find if two given numbers are in the same row, without using `WHERE` and `OR` in MySQL.

The table schema is like this

```
Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | Field4 | Field5 | Field6
  0        0        3        0        0        4
  1        5        0        0        0        0
  0        0        2        0        6        0
```

For example, I would like to know if 3 and 6 are in the same row, and return `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

I am looking for something like this pesudo code: 
SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE :mynumber AND :myothernumber is :inthesamerow?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Open-ended "How to" questions are difficult to answer, and tend to generate follow-up discussions. To improve your chances of getting a helpful answer, [edit] your question to provide greater focus on the specific problem you're facing. See [ask].

Comment: *"Good afternoon"* - It's still "morning" here ;-)

Comment: There's no other way for me to explane, I've really no ideas to suggest...

Comment: Your data example suggests that your columns are most likely VARCHAR and not an INT type, correct? Unless it's unsigned. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

Comment: The next answare has resolved this problem :) 
Thank you guys, and @Fred -ii- not where I live :)

Comment: prego Jasmine, buona giornata, *ciao!* (io capito).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mysql IN commando

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'valueA' IN(field1, field2, field3, field4, ..) AND 'valueB' IN(field1, field2, field3, field4, ..);`

Comment: This is helped me alot, now it's working, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93bb8e/2

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (Field1=3 OR Field2=3 OR Field3=3 OR Field4=3 OR Field5=3 OR Field6=3  )
   AND (Field1=6 OR Field2=6 OR Field3=6 OR Field4=6 OR Field5=6 OR Field6=6  )
```

Comment: Thank you for the answare, I cannot like this, because the numbers change usually, and I've more than two or 3 rows, this is an ex...

Comment: this query will return as many rows as many match to the clause you asked for

Comment: @JasmineVismitananda, why do you think this suggestion will not work? did you tried at least?

Comment: Alex, you could as well use `where 3 in (field1,field2, ...)`

Comment: @Rahul probably, but I whould prefer to keep it as is

Comment: Yes, but I've to filter in PDO 12 numbers :) with IN as @sanderbee  and Rahul suggested working better, thank you alot for your fast help!

Comment: if you use php PDO named parameters - you can bind just once I guess